# How to fetch all reports column records using batch apex?

Tags: apex, soql, reports-api, reports-folder

Hi I am trying to fetch all reports columns names using batch apex.I tried with my following code
but still facing error **Variable does not exist: ReportManager**
Can someone help me on this?

```
public class getRecordColumnNames implements
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM Report'
        );
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Report> reports){
        System.debug('reports'+reports);
        // process each batch of records
        for(Report rep : reports){
            String reportId = rep.Id;
            System.debug('reportId'+reportId);
            Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId);
            Reports.ReportMetadata rm = results.getReportMetadata();
            System.debug('Detail columns: ' + rm.getDetailColumns());
        } 
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed!');
       
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want the column names, why do you need to run the reports?  Can't you just do a getDescribe?

Comment: I think there is a symbol clash with variable `reports` in the argument list to `execute()`. Change `reports` to `records` or something